# how to universally set the back navigation button background image for all the pushed view controllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, background-image, back-button

We are setting the background image for the navigation bar and the bar button items on the navigation bar. But for a view controller that gets pushed on to the navigation controller, we   don't know how to control the behavior of the back button that got automatically added. Is there a way to do that? and specifically, is there a way to change the background image of the back button as well? Or do we have create/set the back button ourselves?

Comment: You should take a look at the `UINavigationItem` Class Reference.  It has a `backBarButtonItem` property which in turn has a `customView` property which you can customize.

Comment: I need to do the change for the button on UIImagePickerController as well (when need to pick an image from photo library on device), which is the reason why I need an universal solution. Just like what we can do with the UINavigationBar

Comment: Could you do what you want with an iOS 5's [appearance proxy](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)?

Comment: @inwit, yes, that's the solution that I wanted. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer goes with iOS5.0's [appearance proxy](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5). kudos to @inwit.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subclass of UIViewController that will be pushed on as new View Controllers buy navigation Controller. Then I would set the back button in the viewDidLoad, so every VC that will use this class will show this back button unless it is overridden.

Comment: yeah, but for UIImagePickerController, that won't work. and that's the problem that's bothering me.